# Quantitative method for Monte Carlo Convergence Check

Tags: monte-carlo, convergence

I did some Monte Carlo simulation based on empirical data and would like to know if there are any quantitative approach to evaluate results' convergence. So far, I am visually check the cumulative mean value for my outputs. Below is a simplified my MC approach and thanks for any suggestions:

1. Variable A is a 100k*1 vector, and variable B is a vector of 500 rows
2. Each step, randomly sample n rows from vector A as A_sample and m rows from vector B as B_sample
3. Multiple A_sample and B_sample as the output variable

Comment: If you know the true value, sum of distance from it should work.

Comment: In this case, I do not ...

Comment: Have you looked https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/what-does-convergence-in-monte-carlo-simulation-mean? Mark Joshi's answer is nice.

Comment: Inverse square root of sample size? Does that work for you?

Comment: @SmallChess, thanks for pointing to the thread. Will check if there is a citation for this.

Comment: Mark's answer is 100% correct if that's what you mean.

Comment: I agree with his approach but need to write this in a report with a proper source...

Comment: Mark Joshi is a well known book author on quantitative analysis. Search his name on Amazon. He talks about Monte Carlo convergence in financial modelling in his books. I personally learn Monte Carlo from his books.